# $\mathfrak{A} \models \phi \iff |A| = n$ for any $n$.

Tags: first-order-logic

For any $n$ write a such formula $\phi$ that $$\mathfrak{A} \models \phi \iff |A| = n$$

My solution:
$$\phi  = (\exists a_n \in A \wedge \exists a_{n-1} \in A \setminus \{a_n\} \wedge ... \wedge \exists a_1 \in A \setminus \{a_n, ..., a_2\} \neg \exists a \ a \in A \setminus \{a_n, .., a_1\} )$$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It expresses the right idea, but it isn’t correct if you’re supposed to find a formula in first-order logic with equality: quite apart from anything else, the underlying set $A$ isn’t available to you in the formal language. You need to say something like this:

$$\exists x_1\,\exists x_2\,\ldots\,\exists x_n\,\forall x_{n+1}\,\left(\bigwedge_{1\le k<\ell\le n}\neg(x_k=x_\ell)\land\bigvee_{1\le k\le n}(x_{n+1}=x_k)\right)\;.$$

The big conjunction is an abbreviation for

$$\begin{align*}
&\neg(x_1=x_2)\land\neg(x_1=x_3)\land\ldots\land\neg(x_1=x_n)\\
&\qquad\land\neg(x_2=x_3)\land\neg(x_2=x_4)\land\ldots\land\neg(x_2=x_n)\\
&\qquad\;\vdots\\
&\qquad\land\neg(x_{n-1}=x_n)\;,
\end{align*}$$

and the big disjunction works is a similar abbreviation.

It may be intuitively more appealing to move the universal quantifier immediately in front of the big disjunction:

$$\exists x_1\,\exists x_2\,\ldots\,\exists x_n\,\left(\bigwedge_{1\le k<\ell\le n}\neg(x_k=x_\ell)\land\forall x_{n+1}\,\left(\bigvee_{1\le k\le n}(x_{n+1}=x_k)\right)\right)\;.$$

This is equivalent to the other version.

Comment: 1. Your formula allows that there is more elements than $n$. It can exists $x_{n+1} $ element which satisfies your condition. 
2. "set A isn’t available to you in the formal language". So what is available?

Comment: @Logic: 1. Good; you saw that. Do you see the simple modification of my expression that is required to solve that problem? 2. The symbols of your formal language. I expect that these are the two quantifiers, the usual logical connectives, a countably infinite collection of variables, and `=`.

Comment: Yes, I see it. Just expand our formula for $x_\{n+1\}$ and it negate it.

Comment: Brian M. Scott. Thanks :)

Comment: @Logic: Not quite: you’ll want a universal quantifier for that one. I’ll make the change in my answer, just to make sure. (You’re welcome.)

Comment: I mean the same :). becasue: $ \neg \forall \phi \iff \exists \neg \phi $ :)

Comment: I didn't clearly what I mean before.